# RDFlib parsing large turtle files memory error

Tags: python, parsing, rdflib, turtle-rdf

I'm trying to parse large .ttl file 1,4 Gb with a help of rdflib in Python and getting memory error.
I've already tried to open triple store in rdflib `g.open("store", create=True)`, but then parsing is never ending story.

```
import rdflib
from rdflib import Graph, Literal, Namespace, URIRef, BNode
from rdflib.namespace import OWL, RDF, RDFS, XSD, SKOS


g = rdflib.Graph()
g.open("store", create=True)
g.parse("C:/Users/tim/Desktop/MEDCT.ttl", format='ttl')
```

Is this a right way to open a local triple store in rdflib or something is missing?

I know that for such a large .ttl files it's suggested to use *Raptor with the Redland Python Bindings*, but I'm not even able to install and import this RDF library in Python, because it's not findable at all.

Could you share your experience how did you parse large turtle files?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://hub.docker.com/r/amoeba/redland-python) a docker image that has Python3 + Redland. We use it in production, [here's](https://github.com/DataONEorg/slinky/blob/main/d1lod/d1lod/graph.py) an example of it being used.

Fo large files you might be better off using a triple store like StarDog, GarphDB, Virtuoso, etc.